# Navigate through textfields in UITableView swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

Trying to navigate through text fields in `UITableView`. Able to navigate through text fields on simple view but not getting how to navigate when text fields are in `UITableView`.

Below is the code tried so far:

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField)
{

    //textField.inputAccessoryView = numberToolbar
    if(textField == txtConfirmPassword)
    {
        textField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.Done
    }
    else
    {
        textField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.Next
    }
}
```

Please guide thanks.

Update:

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField)
{
    if(delegate != nil)
    {
        delegate?.performSelector(NSSelectorFromString("editingTextField"))
    }

    if(textField.tag == 3)
    {
        textField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.Done
    }
    else
    {
        textField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.Next
    }
}

func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool
{
    if(delegate != nil)
    {
        delegate?.performSelector(NSSelectorFromString("editingDone"))
    }
    if(textField.tag == 3)
    {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        delegate?.performSelector(NSSelectorFromString("editingDone"))

    }

     let nextTage=textField.tag+1
    // Try to find next responder
    let nextResponder=textField.superview?.viewWithTag(nextTage) as UIResponder!

    if (nextResponder != nil){
        // Found next responder, so set it.
        nextResponder?.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
    else
    {
        // Not found, so remove keyboard
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
    }
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code for Swift 2.1

Here I have taken `SampleTableViewCell` which is a custom cell in which i have created textField.

For the purpose I have just taken the tag based on cell, so while accessing it in the textField's delegate method, You can know the textField is for which cell.

**Here is the code :**

```
//UITableView Delegate

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
     let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SampleTableViewCell
    cell.txtFld.delegate = self;
    cell.txtFld.tag = indexPath.row + 100
        
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.Gray;
    
    
    return cell;
}
```

UPDATE : Here is the delegate for TextField

```
//UITextField Delegate

func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField)
{
    
    //textField.inputAccessoryView = numberToolbar
    if(textField.tag == 100)
    {
        textField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.Done
    }
    else
    {
        textField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.Next
    }
}
```

Here I have navigate to next textfield by clicking the return button of text field.

```
// called when 'return' key pressed. return NO to ignore.
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool
{
    textField.resignFirstResponder();
    
    if(textField.tag == 100)
    {
        let txtFld = self.tblList.viewWithTag(101);
        txtFld?.becomeFirstResponder();
    }
    
    return true;
}
```

Comment: it's not calling delegates of text field, implemented delegate = self and taken above also UITextFieldDelegate

Comment: Have you included the UITextFieldDelegate in the view controller? See we have set the delegate in the cellForRowAtIndex. So definitely it should call. I have checked this already. Just check there and let me know

Comment: no problem  i got, that's my error delegates will work in custom cell class.

Comment: But above not defined how to navigate to next textfield

Comment: it is returning on click next

Comment: Just make the next textField as the first responder. You can get the next text field by tag. Check my answer

Comment: It is working here while I am testing. But I wonder how it could not work there. may be you are missing something. Show the code what have you tried.

Comment: Where are you making the next text field as first responder like i did in "textFieldShouldReturn" ???

Comment: Still I did not find. Can you check my resignFirstResponder and Your resignFirstResponder ?? Check each line of code you can get what is missing. You are using resignFirstResponder. but you need to do "become firstResponder" look at my answer

    if(textField.tag == 100)
    {
        let txtFld = self.tblList.viewWithTag(101);
        txtFld?.becomeFirstResponder();
    }

Comment: getting "nextResponder" nil

Comment: I am sorry to ask, but do you have basic understanding for the iOS development. Why are you force cast to UIResponder. If you could have copy paste my code then also it would work I guess. If you find difficulties check out the demo project here : https://github.com/janmenjayarout/Demo/commits/master and see. If it is helpful, accept the answer and up vote the answer.

Comment: no problem, thanks for the help so far, will up vote when succeed.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `tag` to check if the current `textfield` is the first responder.

*Note: Swift 3.*

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // let's say that you are reading the date from an array...
        return myArray.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell") as! TableViewCell

        // here you set the tag
        cell.myTextfield?.tag = indexPath.row

        // ...

        return cell
    }


    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
        // now, based on textField you can check (tag == myArray.count - 1 means it is the last)
        textField.returnKeyType = (textField.tag == myArray.count - 1) ? .done : .next
    }
```

Hope that helped.

Comment: can you post swift 2

Comment: come on! don't be too lazy to change it to Swift 2 :) all you have to do is changing the tableView dataSource method names and that's will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Best way for me.

**UITableViewCell**

```
class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
     var nextTextField: (() -> Void)?
}
```

**UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    ...
    cell.nextTextField = { in
        guard let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: indexPath.row + 1, section: 0)) as? CustomTableViewCell else {
            return
        }
        cell.textField.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
    return cell
}
```

**UITextFieldDelegate**

```
...
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textfield: RCTextField) {
    if viewModel.items.count-1 == textfield.tag {
       textField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.done
    } else {
       textField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.next
    }
}
...
```